# method always return "true" value

Tags: android, connection

why this method return "true" value always?

(Both connected and not connected state!)

```
public void onClick(View v)
        {

            if(checkInternetConnection(ctx))
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Online", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Offline", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// checkInternetConnection /////////////////////////////////////

```
public boolean checkInternetConnection(Context cntx) 
    {

        ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager) cntx
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Third question around the same topic? Please do not ask almost the same over and over again. Instead edit the original to be better answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     if (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && 
         con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
              && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected())
                  {   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out using below code:

> ```
>     public static boolean IsNetConnected() {
>     boolean NetConnected = false;
>     try {
>         ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) m_context
>             .getSystemService(m_context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
>         if (connectivity == null) {
>             NetConnected = false;
>         } else {
>             NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
>             if (info != null) {
>                 for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
>                     if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
>                         NetConnected = true;
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     } catch (Exception e) {
>         e.printStackTrace();
>         NetConnected = false;
>     }
>     return NetConnected;
> }
> ```

Comment: what is "m_context"? - can i replace it to "main_Activity.this?"

Comment: Its `Context m_context=ABCactivity.this;` to get activity context. Yes you can replace it with `main_activity.this`.

Comment: Have you provided internet connection permission in your manifest file ? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: yes. i do this :     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />              and            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
public static boolean isOnline(Activity con) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) con
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =(ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (info == null ||
            !connectivityManager.getBackgroundDataSetting()) {

   // No Network detected

        //return;
    }
```